# JavaFX program can not run without admin privileges after deployment

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, deployment, shadowjar

I have developed a JavaFX program that uses a derby embedded database. I am using JDK 11.0.10, IntelliJ 2020.3.1, JavaFX 14.0.1 and Gradle 6.3.

For the jar file, I use `shadowJar` to make a working jar file. Then, I wrap the jar file to make an .exe file using **Launch4j**: The executable file works **fine**.

My problem now is after I make an installer of my program with **Inno Setup Compiler**, the .exe file **won't work** unless I run it with **admin privileges**. I can wrap a **Manifest** with the executable to make it run as administrator every time but I was wondering where is the problem and is there any way to fix it to make the executable run normally.

Comment: you might need to sign it somehow